# Writing ODE system with a complex variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I'm looking at the system of ODEs:

$$\begin{cases}\dot{x} = -y + kx + xy^2\\
\dot{y} = x + ky - x^2\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to introduce a complex variable $z = x+iy$ to write this as a single first order equation so that I can then find an approximation for the limit cycle.

So far I have that $\dot{z} = (k+i)z + xy^2 - ix^2$ and I'm having difficulty with the last two terms, in particular they are different order in x and y so I'm struggling to see how I could replace them with a simple function of z.

Thanks

Comment: z=x+iy   so $$x=\frac{z+z_{c}}{2}\\y=\frac{z-z_{c}}{2i}\\z_{c}=x-iy$$ put them in equation ,then you have an equation in z terms

Comment: @Wooster it is well known that $\dot z=f(z)$ does  not  have  a  limit  cycle(isolated closed orbit) when $f$ is  a holomorphic function. So as Darya Khosrotash said, you need to use $\bar{z}$.Any way your interesting question remind me the following statment of my superviosor: He said that "I think $H(2)$ is finite with some motivation from hyperbolic geometry:Every quadratic system can be written in the form $\dot z=P(z,\bar{z})$...." I  do not know what was his motivation to apply hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: By $H(2)$ I mean a uniform upper bound  for the number of  a  polynomial vector field $$\begin{cases} \dot x=P(x,y)\\ \dot y=Q(x,y) \end{cases}$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynopmial of degree 2

Comment: Thank you for that interesting observation, I was expecting a nice analytic function of $z$ so that's why I was confused!

Comment: I've made the $z$ substitutions, but it now seems impossible to make any first order approximation of this?

Comment: @Wooster thank you very much for your comment I approach to your post just now and I find your comment to me. But I did not find in my "inbox" any message from you. I think that you forget to add for example atsigne+AliTaghavi or some thing like this. Without this atsigne+name one would not be realize your new comment automatically. any way, best wishes for your research:)

Comment: "it now seems impossible to make any first order approximation of this" ?? The first order approximation at $(0,0)$ is $(\dot x,\dot y)=(-y+kx,x+ky)$, equivalent to $\dot z=(i+k)z$.